# Problem with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

> Date: Sun, 31 Oct 2010 21:12:24 +0600
>   From: jim@google.com
>   X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>   Message-ID: <1176875350.20101031211224@goole.com>
>   To: jim2@google.com
>   Subject: MySubject
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Hello from Jim.

Help get the information. I need to have in the array as follows:

> Sun, 31 Oct 2010 21:12:24
>   jim@google.com
>   jim2@google.com
>   MySubject
>   Hello from Jim

If it is possible through regular expressions. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Not necessarily through regular expressions.

Comment: regex might not be the best solution for this

Comment: Yes, it its possible, but here on SO we are not very keen about writing all of your code for you. Please go along and try. If you have any specific questions about how to match certain parts in a regex you are welcome to ask them.

Comment: Please include the regular expression that you have a problem with.

Comment: I don't think you can extract all this with singe regex, I think you must read line by line and match against few regex-es

Comment: Not necessarily through regular expressions. Simple, im very beginner.

Comment: Every time I see the title of this question I smile a little at its redundancy! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a dictionary of keys vs values with the following code. It makes the assumption that the keys are unique.

```
var lookupDictionary=
    Regex
        .Matches(src, "(.+?): (.+)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value,m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

So, to get the `To` field you could:

```
lookupDictionary["To"]
```

To grab the body, you'll need a separate expression:

```
var match=Regex.Match(src, "(?<=.*\n\n).*");
var body=match.Success ? match.Value : null;
```

Potentially, you might be dealing with CRLF line endings, in which case the Regex would be:

```
var match=Regex.Match(src, "(?<=.*\r\n\r\n).*");
var body=match.Success ? match.Value : null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.If I knew how, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best NOT to use regex. Instead, read the text line-by-line.

The header lines consist of a key, a colon (:) and a value and end with a blank line. The rest is the (mail) body.

It would be fairly easy for you to filter out the headers you want and the rest of the text.

If you have problems with any of the steps, feel free to ask again. But include what you have tried so far.

EDIT: as to why not regexes: the format is fairly simple, so you can easily get at the values you want without the overhead of filtering it through a regex. And if you want a single regex to get at only the values you want, that would get very difficult quickly. Also, especially for a newbie, reading line-by-line is much easier to understand.

Comment: Although you recommend against Regex, you don't explain why. What's your reasoning?

Comment: Agreed, if you don't grok Regex, it's probably unsafe to go the Regex route because it's cut'n'paste blackmagic.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will give the result expected

```
MatchCollection mColl = Regex.Matches(txtContent.Text.Trim() ,"(?<=:).+");
for (int i = 0; i < mColl.Count; i++)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(mColl[i].Value.ToString().Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd go about it without regex:

```
var lines = msg.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);

var headerLines = lines.TakeWhile(s => s != string.Empty);
var bodyLines = lines.SkipWhile(s => s != string.Empty).Skip(1);

string body = bodyLines.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + Environment.NewLine + s2);
var headers = (from hl in headerLines
               select new { Key = hl.Split(new []{':'}, 2)[0].Trim()
                          , Value = hl.Split(new[] {':'}, 2)[1].Trim()}).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Where `msg` in the first line is your message and headers combined, as displayed in the question.

The extra `Skip(1)` for `bodyLines` makes sure you don't take the blank line that indicates that the body is starting.

The `Aggregate` method joins `bodyLines` together again with newlines.

The final linq query splits each header line into a key and a value and then turns that into a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

To view what you have, access it like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(headers["Date"]);
Console.WriteLine(headers["From"]);
Console.WriteLine(headers["To"]);
Console.WriteLine(headers["Subject"]);
Console.WriteLine(body);
```

I prefer this to using regex because I only have to know C# to read it, I don't also need to know regex. It might not be as efficient as regex, though, due to all the linq.